# How to permanently setup screen position and order in Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, display, display-settings

I have a laptop with two monitors: one connected through to VGA the second one connected through HDMI using an adapter from Display Port to HDMI. Because I don't work with the laptop at all and I keep it closed then I have setup them as follow:

- Monitor 3 (identified by Fedora as 3rd): it's my main screen and it goes to my left
- Monitor 2 (identified by Fedora as 2nd): is joined with the 3rd monitor and it goes to my right

Sometimes when I disconnect the VGA or the Display Port this configuration is lost and I need to take care of it again and again.

Is there any way to have this setup permanently? I believe that Fedora 25 get rid of XOrg in favor of Wayland.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back to `xorg` if really needed.

I'm currently on Korora (a spinoff of Fedora25) and succesfully running on `xorg`, mainly because of compatibilty with `synergy-gtk`)

For reverting to `xor`g on fedora25 read this:
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/96134/how-can-i-set-xorg-as-a-default-on-fedora-25/

I'm interested in this topic, since I'm trying a third screen in Korora, which works, however I suspect something of Korara is in the way of displaying my (rotated) monitor windows correctly.